# PCA for data set using Emgu

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am trying to perform PCA on a data set currently I have 8 sets of data and for each piece of data I have 618 pieces of information about it. Below is the code I have tried so far:

```
        double[,] RawData = new double[8, 618];

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)//Copies Data to Emgu Matrix
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 618; j++)
            {
                double val = Convert.ToDouble(DataList[i][j]);
                RawData.SetValue(val, i, j);
            }
        }

        Matrix<Double> DataMatrix = new Matrix<Double>(RawData);
        Matrix<Double> Mean = new Matrix<Double>(1, 618);
        Matrix<Double> EigenValues = new Matrix<Double>(1, 618);
        Matrix<Double> EigenVectors = new Matrix<Double>(618, 618);

        CvInvoke.cvCalcPCA(DataMatrix, Mean, EigenValues, EigenVectors, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.PCA_TYPE.CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL);

        Matrix<Double> PC1 = new Matrix<Double>(1, 618);
        for (int i = 0; i < 618; i++)
             PC1[0, i] = EigenVectors[0, i];

        Matrix<Double> Results = new Matrix<Double>(8, 1);

        CvInvoke.cvProjectPCA(DataMatrix, Mean, PC1, Results);

        TestStatus.Items.Add("PCA Projection Results = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            TestStatus.Items.Add(Convert.ToString(DataMatrix[i, 0]));
        }
```

Emgu.CV.Util.CvException: OpenCV: (evals0.cols == 1 || evals0.rows == 1) && ecount0 <= ecount && evects0.cols == evects.cols && evects0.rows == ecount0

at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvErrorHandler(Int32 status, String funcName, String errMsg, String fileName, Int32 line, IntPtr userData)

at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvCalcPCA(IntPtr data, IntPtr avg, IntPtr eigenvalues, IntPtr eigenvectors, PCA_TYPE flags)
   at Project_3._0.MainWindow.Capture_3D_Face_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in f:\Project\Project 3.0\Project 3.0\MainWindow.xaml.cs:line 516

Which is being caused by the line: (which is in the code above)

```
        CvInvoke.cvCalcPCA(DataMatrix, Mean, EigenValues, EigenVectors, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.PCA_TYPE.CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL);
```

How do I set up matrices correctly for the PCA to function?

Answer (score 1):

In the code you provided, shouldn't it be

```
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.PCA_TYPE.CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW
```

instead of

```
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.PCA_TYPE.CV_PCA_DATA_AS_COL
```

(note the last 3 chars of each sencence)

Answer (score 0):

You could look into source code of emguCV and see which of the conditions in the line mentioned in error is triggered. As I have only OpenCV, I cannot help more, because my version of PCA does not have such an assertion.

There might be also some magic like "You must use float not double" involved.

Comment: The Doubles seem to work fine. I found these brackets (1, 618) should be (1,8) and (618, 618) should be (8,8). Although now I am having a problem with CvInvoke.cvProjectPCA(Data, Mean, EigenVectors, Results); don't suppose you have any idea what size the results matrix should be?

Comment: You mean the projected matrix? In [OCV PCA Docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#pca-project) it says, that it will have as many columns as the input matrix, and rows are bound either by maxComponents or by number of coords used to create PCA, so I'd bet on 618.

Comment: Yeah sorry the projected matrix, I have tried creating a matrix of size (8,8), (1,8), (1,618), (8,618) and (618,618) and the inverse of all of these. But none seem to work. The only way I have gotten it to work so far is as a square matrix, replacing all 618 with the value of 8 and placing the original Eigen vector matrix into the Project function.

Comment: The projected matrix will have 8 columns (the same number of vectors as the data). The [documentation](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.5.0.0/Help/html/d99375b3-9df6-033a-e163-798c0cb71e7f.htm) says that result has to have the same number of columns and not less rows than the eigenvectors. 
As I see, You are trying to resolve that problem by force. Do You have the basic knowledge of what PCA does?
Also, try to transpose eigenvectors matrix. Documentation says that they should be one vector per row, and You have them one by column from the CalcPCA().

Comment: Looking into docs, You should have eVals(1,8), eVecs(8,8), mean(1,618) to CalcPCA,and put mean as is, eVecs^T and eVals as they are to project.

Comment: Thank you for your help, looking again I needed to transpose the mean matrix and the projected matrix needed to be of size(8, 618)